# How to grep a particular position line from the result?

Tags: unix, grep

I grep  a pattern from a directory and the 4 lines before that pattern, I need to further grep the top line from each result , but not getting how to do .
Please suggest regarding this.

The problem explained with example :

in  a directory 'direktory'
there are multiple files with different name like 20130611 and 2013400 etc..
the data wrote in the files, which I am interested in is like this :

```
[
My name is 
.....
......
......
Name has been written above
]
```

now in every instance "Name has been written above" is written in the unit of lines but the value keep on changing in place of "My name is" so I want to grep this particular line from every occurrence .

Please suggest some method to get the result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you combine the use of `grep` with `head -1` somehow?

Comment: @nurdglaw : Thanks for replying : I did not get how I should combine head , I thought of that , but could not found the way as the each result has to be checked individually , but the grep I am using  will give collective result for the whole directory..

Comment: Please add to your question (part of) one of your input files along with the desired output from that part of the file? What are you going to do with the output - will you just read it, or are you intending to further process it - perhaps put it in a database, display it on a web page - if so, it might be easier to combine all the processing steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a@x:/tmp$ cat namefile
[
My name is 
.....
......
......
Name has been written above
]
a@x:/tmp$ cat namefile | grep -B 4 "Name has been written above" | head -1
My name is
```

Where "4" can be replaced by N i.e. number of lines the target data lies above the grepped line

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
for file in $(ls <wherever>)
do

    # Tell the user which file we're looking at

    echo ""
    echo $file
    echo ""

    # Output the first line of the file

    head -1 $file

    # Output the line continaing <pattern> and the four
    # preceding lines

    <your grep command here>
done
```

Comment: Thanks for replying

but in my each file there are many occurrence of this unit of lines